# Should we complain about the resources linked in answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

When linking to documentation for a proprietary product like Java, I believe that it is sufficient to say "Here is the [Java 7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)" because it is the canonical reference material created by the company themselves. However when it comes to C++, it's a little more sketchy.

In my experience, cplusplus.com, i.e. [Why is the cplusplus website bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad) is frowned upon for sometimes having incorrect information and because of frustration of its appearance to being an authoritative source (website title as well as being popular on google). I feel this is similar to [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/), a website which discourages the use of W3Schools.

The superior alternative is cppreference.com, a wiki site that in my experience tends to condense material directly from the standard into layman terms. However, it's not perfect and it's not an authoritative source either.

In both of these sites, referring them as "the" documentation is probably incorrect, because it implies that they're authoritative reference material and that they're infallible. I recently made a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26667067/3920237) requesting a change although I'm unsure if it's too pedantic. Despite cplusplus.com being generally frowned upon, I still see answers to it that carelessly refer to it as "the" documentation and comments decrying it may be just noise.

A similar issue exists with linking to the man pages because there are several sites which offer them and the best way to get accurate man pages for one's platform is to run it on their machine. In one situation, I told someone that cplusplus.com is bad and that they should link to linux.die.net instead, although I was unaware that the site has advertisements on it and their argument was that cplusplus.com's table is easier to read.

Is it necessary to be so pedantic about which source is used if it's generally the same information?

---

Here are examples (not to call anyone out, but rather to be illustrative). Often we use the draft standard n3337 for C++11 answers (the answerer did not reference which document so I made an assumption to which he did not complain and edited it in).

[What does "new int[];" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404384/what-does-new-int-do/26404545#comment41459248_26404545)

> here's the standardeese from N3337: *[..]* (12.3" AFAICS it is
>   identical to C++11 (N3290). It does not match the quoted text in the
>   answer.

[Interaction between decltype and class member name shadowing an external name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681873/interaction-between-decltype-and-class-member-name-shadowing-an-external-name/26682543#comment41970629_26682543)

> You cited a *draft*, which means little. I'm showing you how to cite
>   the actual standard, which is authoritative.

Comment: Go register cminusminus.com explaining why cplusplus.com is a bad reference. :P

Comment: I don't see how citing the last draft would be bad. There should only be typographical changes after that. Maybe someone just has to show his superiority by having the access to the expensive thing at his company? In the Fortran tag and other Fortran forums this issue never arose.

Comment: The last draft does not necessarily represent the draft that was sent for standardization.  There could be changes, occasionally significant ones, between the last publicly available draft and the final standard

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not unnecessary.  An authoritative standard is always superior to some website's interpretation, and should be used *whenever available*.  If the standard is bulky and hard to digest, link to it primarily, and then add an additional link for "this guys website explains it well".  This prevents confusion as to what's the real standard and allows people to reference the authoritative docs where it counts.  They then know that by following the link to "Steve's K-12 C++ tutorial", they're consuming Steve's interpretation and not the real thing.  I always try to do this, and absolutely hate when "Joe's RPM Depo" get's linked to as the only supporting evidence for a question about YUM (or something, you get the point).

If no authoritative documentation exists...  say that before you link to "Bob's blog shack".  In the event where no authoritative source exists and you have to choose between whatever's out there, it doesn't **really** matter, because they're all non-authoritative.  That said, if you think the trust level between two non-authoritative sources is really different...   say something. At that point it's a judgement call, i.e. how much do you think it will improve the answer?

Comment: By "exists" do you include paywalled resources such as the official standards? For example, should the answerer expect the asker (and subsequent searchers) to find a paywalled resource cited in the answer sufficient?

Comment: @tepples: In such cases, mentioning the standard and quoting the appropriate parts is the recommended way, no link needed at all.

Comment: Some people will complain that draft standards are not official and therefore are not authoritative compared to the printed version. However, the draft versions are free and available to everyone.

Comment: @remyabel: for all practical purposes, the "latest draft" is usually as good a canonical reference as the (expensive!) "final" one. Had it not been from a high rated long-time SO user, I'd frown upon such a comment as `-Whighly-pedantic`. As it is, I'm clueless to the underlying reason of that particular comment.